# How to get a value from an Array of object without calling the key (i've searched through the internet can't found the exact/similar problem to this)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So i had this kind of const value

```
    const testingObjArr = [
    {
      asdasdasdasdds:"testing 123"
    },
    {
      bcdefghasdkl:"testing 456"
    },
    {
      asdklqwoepskalx:"testing 678"
    },
 ]
```

I want to getting the value only and push that into a new array
like this

```
["testing 123", "testing 456", "testing 678"]
```

I've tried using Object.values and similar ways but always return the same values when log it.

this is the last method that i used

```
console.log( "testing objs",Object.values(obj).map(i => i).flat())
```

I also use this loop to getting the values

```
const testingObjArrLength = Object.keys(testingObjArr).length;
const finalDatas = [];
for(let x=0; x<testingObjArrLength; x++) {
  const datas = Object.values(testingObjArr)[x]
  finalDatas.push(datas);
}
console.log("finaldatas", finalDatas);
```

This is the results in console log

[image]

can anyone give me an advice? appreciate that if not tagged this with duplicate, because i've been around searching for the solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) as callback.

```js
const
    data = [{ asdasdasdasdds: "testing 123" }, { bcdefghasdkl: "testing 456" }, { asdklqwoepskalx: "testing 678" }],
    values = data.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(values);
```